# my Java codes generates a query --> delete from 'emp' , but i need it as--> delete from emp. Please help me

Tags: java, jdbc

my Java codes generates a query --> delete from 'emp' , but i need it as--> delete from emp. Please help me

```
void deleteData(Map records) throws SQLException { 
   String delQuery = "delete from ? where empid = ?" 
   String tbname = String records.get(tabName); 
   String empid = String records.get(empid); 
   PreparedStatement data = getPreparedStatement(DelQuery); 
   data.setString(1,tbname); 
   data.setString(2,empid); 
   System.out.println("Query is ---->"+data.toString()); 
   ResultSet rst = data.executeQuery();
 }
```

when i see the console for errors , it shows :

```
Query is ----> DELETE FROM 'emp' WHERE empid = '21'

Could not execute sql command - Original message: null
```

Comment: Do not do this. Make one DAO for each table. And write methods that take _field-values_ as parameter, and not pass tableName and field-names. Apart from making your code behave erratically.. this will be a pain in neck while refactoring tables.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set a table name as a parameter unfortunately. You have to code it in as part of the SQL.

```
delQuery = "DELETE FROM " + tbname + " WHERE empid = ?"
```

Obviously the usual caveats about ensuring your table name fields are sanitized apply.

Comment: Thanks Phill, your suggestion worked, But I was thinking of making delQuery as private static final , outside the function...is there any way of it. coz table name wil b fetched in the function itself using Map values.

Comment: @Shweta What you could do is store it as a String like this: DELETE FROM %s WHERE empid = ? - and then use String.format(delQuery, tableName) to substitute the table name.

Comment: Ultimately I would look into a framework like Mybatis though: http://www.mybatis.org/ - all SQL is stored in XML configuration files, and you can do things like setting the table name at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind table names with PreparedStatement, only column values. You can do:

```
...
String tbname = String records.get(tabName);    
String delQuery = "delete from " + tbname + " where empid = ?";
...
```

This won't make it any more vulnerable to injection, as the tableName shouldn't be coming from the user anyway.

Comment: Nikola, User wil give the input as the type of record, where emp is one of them , based on user input only i have to select  the table